# Tutorial: Use macros in a custom pallet - Compile Error

Tags: substrate-node-template

I have looked through other posts on the compile errors for "Use macros in a custom pallet". None of them seemed to get me through the following error. I made sure to have a clean install of `substrate-node-template`. I also traced it to `/Users/****/substrate/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:273:2`. I couldn't find any references to "weights". It appears to be referenceing something which doesn't exist; however, I'm not sure where to go from there as I'm very new at this. Information below:

**Error**

```rs
MacBook-Pro src %  cargo check -p node-template-runtime --release
    Checking pallet-session v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?branch=polkadot-v0.9.42#bca8a29d)
    Checking pallet-template v4.0.0-dev (/Users/****/substrate/substrate-node-template/pallets/template)
    Checking pallet-transaction-payment-rpc-runtime-api v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?branch=polkadot-v0.9.42#bca8a29d)
    Checking pallet-aura v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?branch=polkadot-v0.9.42#bca8a29d)
   Compiling node-template-runtime v4.0.0-dev (/Users/****/substrate/substrate-node-template/runtime)
warning: use of deprecated struct `pallet::_::Store`: 
                 Use of `#[pallet::generate_store(pub(super) trait Store)]` will be removed soon.
                 Check https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/13535 for more details.
  --> pallets/template/src/lib.rs:12:4
   |
12 |   #[pallet::generate_store(pub(super) trait Store)]
   |    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: `#[warn(deprecated)]` on by default

warning: use of deprecated constant `pallet::warnings::ConstantWeight_0::_w`: 
                 It is deprecated to use hard-coded constant as call weight.
                 Please instead benchmark all calls or put the pallet into `dev` mode.
         
                 For more info see:
                     <https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/13798>
  --> pallets/template/src/lib.rs:51:22
   |
51 |     #[pallet::weight(0)]
   |                      ^

warning: use of deprecated constant `pallet::warnings::ConstantWeight_1::_w`: 
                 It is deprecated to use hard-coded constant as call weight.
                 Please instead benchmark all calls or put the pallet into `dev` mode.
         
                 For more info see:
                     <https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/13798>
  --> pallets/template/src/lib.rs:73:22
   |
73 |     #[pallet::weight(0)]
   |                      ^

warning: `pallet-template` (lib) generated 3 warnings
    Checking pallet-grandpa v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?branch=polkadot-v0.9.42#bca8a29d)
error: failed to run custom build command for `node-template-runtime v4.0.0-dev (/Users/****/substrate/substrate-node-template/runtime)`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/Users/****/substrate/substrate-node-template/target/release/build/node-template-runtime-0abb0d4d70014bf7/build-script-build` (exit status: 1)
  --- stdout
  Information that should be included in a bug report.
  Executing build command: RUSTFLAGS="-C target-cpu=mvp -C target-feature=-sign-ext -C link-arg=--export-table -Clink-arg=--export=__heap_base -C link-arg=--import-memory  " SKIP_WASM_BUILD="" "/Users/****/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/bin/cargo" "rustc" "--target=wasm32-unknown-unknown" "--manifest-path=/Users/****/substrate/substrate-node-template/target/release/wbuild/node-template-runtime/Cargo.toml" "--color=always" "--profile" "release"
  Using rustc version: rustc 1.70.0 (90c541806 2023-05-31)


  --- stderr
     Compiling pallet-template v4.0.0-dev (/Users/****/substrate/substrate-node-template/pallets/template)
  warning: use of deprecated struct `pallet::_::Store`: 
                   Use of `#[pallet::generate_store(pub(super) trait Store)]` will be removed soon.
                   Check https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/13535 for more details.
    --> /Users/****/substrate/substrate-node-template/pallets/template/src/lib.rs:12:4
     |
  12 |   #[pallet::generate_store(pub(super) trait Store)]
     |    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
     |
     = note: `#[warn(deprecated)]` on by default

  warning: use of deprecated constant `pallet::warnings::ConstantWeight_0::_w`: 
                   It is deprecated to use hard-coded constant as call weight.
                   Please instead benchmark all calls or put the pallet into `dev` mode.
           
                   For more info see:
                       <https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/13798>
    --> /Users/****/substrate/substrate-node-template/pallets/template/src/lib.rs:51:22
     |
  51 |     #[pallet::weight(0)]
     |                      ^

  warning: use of deprecated constant `pallet::warnings::ConstantWeight_1::_w`: 
                   It is deprecated to use hard-coded constant as call weight.
                   Please instead benchmark all calls or put the pallet into `dev` mode.
           
                   For more info see:
                       <https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/13798>
    --> /Users/****/substrate/substrate-node-template/pallets/template/src/lib.rs:73:22
     |
  73 |     #[pallet::weight(0)]
     |                      ^

     Compiling node-template-runtime v4.0.0-dev (/Users/****/substrate/substrate-node-template/runtime)
  warning: `pallet-template` (lib) generated 3 warnings
  error[E0437]: type `WeightInfo` is not a member of trait `pallet_template::Config`
     --> /Users/****/substrate/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:273:2
      |
  273 |     type WeightInfo = pallet_template::weights::SubstrateWeight<Runtime>;
      |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not a member of trait `pallet_template::Config`

  error[E0433]: failed to resolve: could not find `weights` in `pallet_template`
     --> /Users/****/substrate/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:273:37
      |
  273 |     type WeightInfo = pallet_template::weights::SubstrateWeight<Runtime>;
      |                                        ^^^^^^^ could not find `weights` in `pallet_template`

  Some errors have detailed explanations: E0433, E0437.
  For more information about an error, try `rustc --explain E0433`.
  error: could not compile `node-template-runtime` (lib) due to 2 previous errors
```

**`/substrate-node-template/pallets/template/src/lib.rs`**

```rs
#![cfg_attr(not(feature = "std"), no_std)]

// Re-export pallet items so that they can be accessed from the crate namespace.
pub use pallet::*;

#[frame_support::pallet]
pub mod pallet {
  use frame_support::pallet_prelude::*;
  use frame_system::pallet_prelude::*;

  #[pallet::pallet]
  #[pallet::generate_store(pub(super) trait Store)]
  pub struct Pallet<T>(_);

  /// Configure the pallet by specifying the parameters and types on which it depends.
  #[pallet::config]
  pub trait Config: frame_system::Config {
    /// Because this pallet emits events, it depends on the runtime's definition of an event.
    type RuntimeEvent: From<Event<Self>> + IsType<<Self as frame_system::Config>::RuntimeEvent>;
  }

  // Pallets use events to inform users when important changes are made.
  // Event documentation should end with an array that provides descriptive names for parameters.
  #[pallet::event]
  #[pallet::generate_deposit(pub(super) fn deposit_event)]
  pub enum Event<T: Config> {
    /// Event emitted when a claim has been created.
    ClaimCreated { who: T::AccountId, claim: T::Hash },
    /// Event emitted when a claim is revoked by the owner.
    ClaimRevoked { who: T::AccountId, claim: T::Hash },
  }

  #[pallet::error]
  pub enum Error<T> {
    /// The claim already exists.
    AlreadyClaimed,
    /// The claim does not exist, so it cannot be revoked.
    NoSuchClaim,
    /// The claim is owned by another account, so caller can't revoke it.
    NotClaimOwner,
  }

  #[pallet::storage]
  pub(super) type Claims<T: Config> = StorageMap<_, Blake2_128Concat, T::Hash, (T::AccountId, T::BlockNumber)>;

  // Dispatchable functions allow users to interact with the pallet and invoke state changes.
  // These functions materialize as "extrinsics", which are often compared to transactions.
  // Dispatchable functions must be annotated with a weight and must return a DispatchResult.
  #[pallet::call]
  impl<T: Config> Pallet<T> {
    #[pallet::weight(0)]
    #[pallet::call_index(1)]
    pub fn create_claim(origin: OriginFor<T>, claim: T::Hash) -> DispatchResult {
      // Check that the extrinsic was signed and get the signer.
      // This function will return an error if the extrinsic is not signed.
      let sender = ensure_signed(origin)?;

      // Verify that the specified claim has not already been stored.
      ensure!(!Claims::<T>::contains_key(&claim), Error::<T>::AlreadyClaimed);

      // Get the block number from the FRAME System pallet.
      let current_block = <frame_system::Pallet<T>>::block_number();

      // Store the claim with the sender and block number.
      Claims::<T>::insert(&claim, (&sender, current_block));

      // Emit an event that the claim was created.
      Self::deposit_event(Event::ClaimCreated { who: sender, claim });

      Ok(())
    }

    #[pallet::weight(0)]
    #[pallet::call_index(2)]
    pub fn revoke_claim(origin: OriginFor<T>, claim: T::Hash) -> DispatchResult {
      // Check that the extrinsic was signed and get the signer.
      // This function will return an error if the extrinsic is not signed.
      let sender = ensure_signed(origin)?;

      // Get owner of the claim, if none return an error.
      let (owner, _) = Claims::<T>::get(&claim).ok_or(Error::<T>::NoSuchClaim)?;

      // Verify that sender of the current call is the claim owner.
      ensure!(sender == owner, Error::<T>::NotClaimOwner);

      // Remove claim from storage.
      Claims::<T>::remove(&claim);

      // Emit an event that the claim was erased.
      Self::deposit_event(Event::ClaimRevoked { who: sender, claim });
      Ok(())
    }
}

}
```

**Cargo.toml**

```
[package]
name = "pallet-template"
version = "4.0.0-dev"
description = "FRAME pallet template for defining custom runtime logic."
authors = ["Substrate DevHub <https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub>"]
homepage = "https://substrate.io"
edition = "2021"
license = "MIT-0"
publish = false
repository = "https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/"

[package.metadata.docs.rs]
targets = ["x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu"]

[dependencies]
codec = { package = "parity-scale-codec", version = "3.2.2", default-features = false, features = [
    "derive",
] }
scale-info = { version = "2.5.0", default-features = false, features = ["derive"] }
frame-benchmarking = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, optional = true, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.42" }
frame-support = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.42" }
frame-system = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.42" }

[dev-dependencies]
sp-core = { version = "7.0.0", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.42" }
sp-io = { version = "7.0.0", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.42" }
sp-runtime = { version = "7.0.0", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.42" }

[features]
default = ["std"]
std = [
    "codec/std",
    "frame-benchmarking?/std",
    "frame-support/std",
    "frame-system/std",
    "scale-info/std",
]
runtime-benchmarks = ["frame-benchmarking/runtime-benchmarks"]
try-runtime = ["frame-support/try-runtime"]
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is outdated.

Check https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/bin/node-template/pallets/template/src/lib.rs.

---

And I think you have ran the `cargo update` locally. Otherwise, the old code should also work.